# How to pass filename to Heroku pg:sql command?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, psql, heroku-postgres

I want to load schema from **structure.sql** file to my Heroku database. On my localhost machine I do as follows and all works just fine, all tables are created:

```
C:\> psql -U postgres -a -d MyApp_development -f C:\MyApp\db\structure.sql
```

I pass a local file name as `-f` option: `-f C:\MyApp\db\structure.sql`

When I do the same on Heroku, it complains that the app is not found. I think that it doesn't understand `-f` option. It cannot find file `C:\MyApp\db\structure.sql` on its server.

So how do I need to provide correct path relative to Heroku? **structure.sql** has to be located here on Heroku:

```
MyApp\db\structure.sql
```

So I need to do something like this:

```
heroku pg:psql -U ... -a -d MyHerokuDB -f MyHerokuAppRoot\db\structure.sql
```

What is `MyHerokuAppRoot`? What with may substitute it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I think that the problem is that Postgresql takes only forward slash (/) as a directory separator. So when I provide Windows style paths, it doesn't work.

I did as follows. I connected to DB first:

```
C:\MyApp>heroku pg:psql DATABASE
```

Then I ran this command:

```
d17q2hrd89o9cu=> \i C:/MyApp/db/structure.sql
```

And all tables mentioned in local **structure.sql** file were created on Heroku hosting.